# How to get the text of all children inside a specific node

Tags: html, xml, xpath, scrapy

I have a node and it contains text and other nodes, which have text too.  I would like to get the text inside that node regardless of what children nodes it has.

For example, I could have this scenario:

```
<span class="title">text text text</span>
```

Or this scenario:

```
<span class="title">text text text <p>text text text</p> <div>text text</div> <span>
```

What I need is all the text inside that **`span`** node.

I tried this:

```
span[@class='title']//text()
```

but the problem is that code didn't work with this scenario:

```
<span class="title">text text <br><br>text text <br><br>text text </span>
```

Comment: What means *not working* ? I tested this: http://pastebin.com/ECR5Z7Xv

Comment: @hek2mgl I mean that it gives me just the text directly inside the node, but when there is `<br>`, it didn't give me the test after that `<br>`

Comment: It indeed does. Have you tried the example I've linked in my first comment?

Comment: `span[@class='title']//text()`is not the same as `span[@class='title']/text()`. Only when using `span[@class='title']/text()` you should arrive at the results you are describing.

Answer (score 1):

The [string value](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#dt-string-value) of your `span` element is returned by the [**`string()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-string) function:

```
string(span[@class='title'])
```

for

```
<span class="title">text text text <p>text text text</p> <div>text text</div> </span>
```

it returns

```
text text text text text text text text
```

as requested.   However, note that

```
<span class="title">text text <br><br>text text <br><br>text text </span>
```

is **not well-formed XML** and so no XPath will work, but if you clean-up the unclosed `br` elements,

```
<span class="title">text text <br/><br/>text text <br/><br/>text text </span>
```

You'll get

```
text text text text text text
```

as expected.